# Issue with: Cannot create an instance of Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.UI.ContentUI.Config.ContentViewDefinitionElement because it is an abstract class

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitefinity, sitefinity-5

I am working on a project using sitefinity and I have run into an error I can't seem to solve. I tried to implement this [Comment Notification](http://www.sitefinity.com/devnet/forums/general-discussions-/email-notification-for-new-comments-at-blogposts#V9jIpvuffUS0zyYp7qRH3Q) fix and something has happened. After changing the ViewType name with my own I get this error:

> Cannot create an instance of Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.UI.ContentUI.Config.ContentViewDefinitionElement because it is an abstract class.

I can't view any pages that have a Blog widget on them...which is all of them!

I restored the DB from a working backup but the error persists. I can't seem to find much about how to fix this, has anyone encountered something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it myself. I Changed the name of something that should not have been changed.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth ahh yes that would have been helpful. I changed the `VeiwName` to match, which caused everything to fail, I was able to find it in the `BlogConfig.config` file.